# From which game is this image of picking a lock on a broken door?

Tags: game-identification

While viewing the image gallery [Video game logic](https://imgur.com/gallery/OeqPR), one image in particular I thought was funny but I have no idea what game it is from:

[image: Screenshot showing a door marked Locked - Very Hard]

What game is this here that requires a lockpick skill of 100 on a door that any normal person could simply reach over and use the doorknob from the other side?

Comment: The keyhole suggests to me a door that can't be opened from either side without the key. These locks are also hard to pick, so this is entirely consistent.

Comment: @xorsyst consitent in the sense of unlocking the door, but in its conditon (and the equipment in the game), destroying or climbing through the door would be an extermely easy task, much easier than unlocking it.

Comment: @ShadowZ. - I always wondered this myself. Like, can I not just use the 58th Tire Iron I've picked up to jimmy open the 200+ year old rotting wood of the door?

Comment: Also: is it bad that I'm pretty sure I know where that screenshot is from in-game?

Comment: @Robotnik and, what about the many explosive devices? That door would probably fall if u chucked a grenade hard enough at it, and not to mention the explosion that could more than likely cause the whole building to collapse.

Comment: If you climb over the door, you will fall out of the world. Fall out. Fallout. Get that? Hahaha (*self-entertaining*)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's from Fallout 3.

You can tell it's not from New Vegas because the CND bar on the NV interface is slightly different-- it includes a marker at 75%.

[image: New Vegas screenshot]
Here's a screenshot from New Vegas with the difference highlighted.

Comment: Good catch! I had forgotten about that subtle UI cue.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I would have mentioned the colour but that's just a default. The NV UI can be green.

Comment: This is from the Lincoln memorial.

Comment: I remember seeing this in Fallout 3, anyone know what was inside?

Comment: I don't see the 75% mark. Can somebody draw an arrow pointing at it?

Comment: @user1306322 It's not in the screenshot because it's not in Fallout 3- that's my point. Look at the NV screenshot in GodEmperorDune's answer.

Comment: I still don't see it in the NV screenshot ×_×

Comment: @user1306322 It's in the second image (with the orange HUD) on the bottom right. The word CND has a bar next to it. 75% of the way across (from left to right) there are two black vertical notches at the top and bottom of the bar.

Comment: Fallout 3 also has the sickly-green tinge filter whereas NV does not.

Comment: A more notable difference is that the new vegas bars have small "cuts" on one side of the bar(s), while FO3 does not.

Answer (score 8):

I agree, the design of this mechanism appears somewhat flawed. However, (as people have stated) this is from Fallout 3, which was released in late 2008, from Bethesda (who also created the similarly epic "Elder Scrolls" series).

It is a free-roam RPG/FPS style game, set in an apocalyptic future after the Nuclear Fallout.

[The Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_3) has a fairly in-depth description of the games timeline and history, and there is also a few wiki sites dedicated purely to Fallout 3, like [this one](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3) that has a far more in-depth and detailed collection of information about the game itself.

Comment: Bethesda did not create the Fallout Series though. It was originally created by Interplay and then bought by Bethesda. Your wording suggest that they have created it, which is not true and I am pretty much nitpicking here, but I could not hold back my fanboy rage there. Sorry :P.

Answer (score 6):

That'd be a screenshot from either Fallout 3 or its semi-sequel, Fallout: New Vegas. The games have a nearly identical UI, and both use most of the same art-assets. Certainly the "broken wooden door" seen above appears in both games, and is sometimes locked in both. There is, unfortunately, nothing unique in the picture above to identify it as belonging to anything other than both games' "generic office" tileset, which is used in a wide variety of environments in both games.

For what it's worth, the HUD in this particular screenshot is the default green color used in Fallout 3. New Vegas's default HUD color is more of a sand brown. However, the color scheme in both games *is* configurable.